# Отредактировать форму регистрации html

Tags: html, css

Есть форма регистрации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня не получается выставить переключатели в один ряд и сделать подписи под инпутами, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это подправить?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 23.5%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.child:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

#form {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

label,
p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  font-size: 11px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

p {
  width: 250px;
}

.img {
  width: 90px;
  padding-left: 82px;
  margin-top: -41px;
}

#number {
  position: relative;
  top: -23px;
}

.menu,
.picinput {
  width: 150px;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.qwe {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 180px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, green, lightgreen, green);
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#button {
  display: none;
}

#form label:nth-of-type(3n) {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">

  <form id="form">
    Фрилансер<input type="radio" name="test" checked value="1"> Предприниматель
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="2">
    <label for="name">Email</label><input id="name" type="name" class="menu" placeholder="example@gmail.com"><span></span><br>
    <label for="surname">Логин</label><input id="surname" type="name" class="menu" placeholder="Log_in"><span>3-15 символов. Допустимы латинские буквы, цифры и знак подчеркивания (_) и дефис (-)</span><br>
    <label for="password">Пароль</label><input id="password" type="password" class="menu" pattern="[0-9]{7,}" placeholder="Введите пароль"><span>
                        от 6 до 24 символов. Допустимы латинские буквы, цифры и знак подчеркивания (_)</span><br>
    <label for="number">Код с картинки <img class="img" src="img.png" alt=""></label><input id="number" type="text" class="picinput" pattern="[0-9]{5}"><span></span>
    <div class="button">
      <label class="qwe" for="button"><input id="button" form="form" type="submit">Зарегистрироваться</label>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Уберите фиксированную ширину для всех элементов - `width: 400px;` - и определяйте её только для тех, которым она действительно нужна.

Answer (score 2):

1. Убираем для всех блоков `*` ширину в `400px`, а задаем ее форме `#form`.
2. Оборачиваем каждую группу полей в блок `form-row`, а `input+span` в `form-group`. Это для того чтобы `span` отображался под `input`.
3. Для выравнивания строкам `.form-row` задаем `dispaly:table;` а внутренним блокам `dispay: table-cell;` . Либо можно заменить на `display:flex` для `.form-row`.

---

Например так:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#form {
  width: 400px;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 23.5%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.child:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

#form {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

label,
p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  width: 250px;
}

.img {
  width: 90px;
  padding-left: 82px;
  margin-top: -41px;
}

#number {
  position: relative;
  top: -23px;
}


/* .menu,
.picinput {
  width: 150px;
} */

.button {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#button {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 180px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, green, lightgreen, green);
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 
#button {
  display: none;
} */

#form .form-row:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 150px;
}

.form-group input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.form-row label {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
}

.form-row {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#form input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
}

.form-group span {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">

  <form id="form">

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>Фрилансер</label>
      <input type="radio" name="test" checked value="1">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>Предприниматель</label>
      <input type="radio" name="test" value="2">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="name">Email</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="name" type="name" class="menu" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="surname">Логин</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="surname" type="name" class="menu" placeholder="Log_in">
        <span>3-15 символов. Допустимы латинские буквы, цифры и знак подчеркивания (_) и дефис (-)</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="password">Пароль</label>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="password" type="password" class="menu" pattern="[0-9]{7,}" placeholder="Введите пароль">
        <span>от 6 до 24 символов. Допустимы латинские буквы, цифры и знак подчеркивания (_)</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="number">Код с картинки <img class="img" src="img.png" alt=""></label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="number" type="text" class="picinput" pattern="[0-9]{5}">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
      <button id="button" type="submit">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

---

Вариант с `flex` [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox):

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#form {
  width: 400px;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 23.5%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.child:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

#form {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

label,
p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  width: 250px;
}

.img {
  width: 90px;
  padding-left: 82px;
  margin-top: -41px;
}

#number {
  position: relative;
  top: -23px;
}


/* .menu,
.picinput {
  width: 150px;
} */

.button {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#button {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 180px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, green, lightgreen, green);
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 
#button {
  display: none;
} */

#form .form-row:nth-of-type(3) {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex-positive: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.form-group input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.form-row label {
  width: 200px;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex-positive: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.form-row {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  display: flex;
}

#form input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
}

.form-group span {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">

  <form id="form">

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>Фрилансер</label>
      <input type="radio" name="test" checked value="1">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label>Предприниматель</label>
      <input type="radio" name="test" value="2">
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="name">Email</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="name" type="name" class="menu" placeholder="example@gmail.com">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="surname">Логин</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="surname" type="name" class="menu" placeholder="Log_in">
        <span>3-15 символов. Допустимы латинские буквы, цифры и знак подчеркивания (_) и дефис (-)</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="password">Пароль</label>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="password" type="password" class="menu" pattern="[0-9]{7,}" placeholder="Введите пароль">
        <span>от 6 до 24 символов. Допустимы латинские буквы, цифры и знак подчеркивания (_)</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="number">Код с картинки <img class="img" src="img.png" alt=""></label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="number" type="text" class="picinput" pattern="[0-9]{5}">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
      <button id="button" type="submit">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: есть подозрения, что `span`-ы после `input`-ов - это будущие появляющиеся подсказки, при неправильном вводе. Но, тут автор что-то не уточнил сразу. Чую, будут ещё вопросы)))

Comment: @UModeL, да, понятно что это подсказки при валидации формы. Расположить их можно как статически так и на абсолютах. Думаю автор будет использовать js для валидации. А а отображение заключается в `display: none\block;`